# Obtener lo contrario del siguiente query en Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

He realizado un query que solo obtiene los numeros de cuenta con su saldo si aparecen en la tabla `saldos`. Al principio era mi objetivo, el cual ahora es todo lo contrario, es decir, poder obtener los numeros de cuenta que no tienen saldo en la tabla `saldos`.

Las tablas de la consulta son las siguientes:

1. **MARCAJE** (dicha tabla tiene los números de cuenta de clientes especificos, como id especificos para gerentes y canales).
2. **SALDOS** (dicha tabla contiene los saldos que tienen los clientes por `id`. Si el cliente no tiene saldo, esta no aparece en la tabla).
3. **CLIENTES** (dicha tabla tiene la informacion de todos los clientes con su numero de cuenta, la relaciono con la tabla `marcaje` por numero de cuenta, ya que como explique en la tabla `marcaje` esta contiene solo clientes especificos (que son los que me importan realmente), tambien la relaciono con la tabla `saldos` por `id`, ya que la tabla `saldos` solo se pueden relacionar por `id` con la tabla `clientes`).
4. **GERENTE** (dicha tabla tiene el `id` de los gerentes necesarios para realizar la consulta).
5. **CANAL** (dicha tabla tiene el `id` de los canales necesarios para realizar la consulta).

*Query #1*, este permite obtener los *números de cuentas* necesarios para poder obtener sus *saldos*. (devuelve 422 *numero de cuenta* que se encuentran en la tabla `marcaje`).

```
select 
        M.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA as cuentas
    from MARCAJE M
inner join CLIENTES C on C.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA = M.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA
inner join GERENTE G on G.ID = M.ID_GERENTE
inner join CANAL CN on CN.ID = M.ID_CANAL
    where CN.ID = '2' and G.ID = '41';
```

*Query #2*, este permite obtener los `saldos` de las cuentas que se encuentran en `marcaje`, no solo las filtradas del primer query, sino todas las cuentas.

```
select
     C.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA   as cuentas
     ,S.SALDO                as saldo_disponible
from CLIENTES C 
      inner join SALDOS S on S.ID = C.ID
      inner join MARCAJE M on M.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA = C.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA
```

Query #3, este es la relación entre el primer y segundo query, obtiene las cuentas del primer query que tienen saldo en el segundo query (devuelven 176 *numero de cuenta* que tienen `saldo`, faltan 247 *numero de cuenta* que son las que no tienen algun tipo de `saldo`).

```
with 

    gerente as (
        select 
                M.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA as cuentas
            from MARCAJE M
        inner join CLIENTES C on C.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA = M.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA
        inner join GERENTE G on G.ID = M.ID_GERENTE
        inner join CANAL CN on CN.ID = M.ID_CANAL
            where CN.ID = '2' and G.ID = '41'
    ),

    saldos as (
        select
                C.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA   as cuentas
               ,S.SALDO                as saldo_disponible
        from CLIENTES C 
            inner join SALDOS S on S.ID = C.ID
            inner join MARCAJE M on M.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA = C.NUMERO_DE_CUENTA
    )

    select
        g.cuentas,
        s.saldo_disponible
    from gerente g, saldos s
    where g.cuentas = s.cuentas;
```

Como lo dije al principio, mi objetivo es conseguir esas 247 *numeros de cuenta* que no tienen `saldo`, lo unico que se me ocurrio fue utilizar la función `not exists` pero no funcionó.

De antemano gracias por leer esto y tratar de ayudarme en dicho problema

Comment: en que version de oracle estas? podes hacer un left join en esa version?

Comment: @gbianchi version 11g

Comment: entonces un left join donde s.cuentas = null es la solucion...

Comment: @gbianchi excelente, muchas gracias

Comment: Ahi agrego una respuesta con eso, asi queda claro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para hacer lo contrario a lo que tenes, no hay que cambiar mucho tu codigo.

Sabemos que con un inner join trae las que estan de los dos lados.. pero si queremos las de un solo lado podemos hacer un left/rigth join y nulificar el otro lado.. de esa forma, solo traeria las que no tienen una relacion del otro lado.

```
select
    g.cuentas,
    s.saldo_disponible
from gerente g left join saldos s on g.cuentas = s.cuentas
where s.cuentas is null;
```